# What letter do you use for a constant placeholder?

Tags: c

I used this in the preprocessor

```
#define SQMETERS_PR_SEC 2
```

And this in the main function

```
printf(" to mow your lawn with a speed of %c.\n\n", SQMETERS_PR_SEC);
```

But the %c just returns a blank space.

What letter do you use for a constant placeholder?

Comment: Your statement will print 2 as an unsigned character, which is unprintable. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Just for future reference and easier searching, the term you are looking for is "format specifier".

Answer (score 6):

That depends, in this case your constant is a small integer, so you'd print it with `%d`.

A string constant however would be printed with `%s`, etc. There's not universal trick to print a constant, regardless of type.

The reason for that is that your "constant" is in reality a macro, which means that at any point beyond of its position `SQMETERS_PR_SEC` gets *textually* replaced with `2`. That's it - no fancy interpretation or anything, it's a textual copy/paste.

Comment: By the way using %s would lead into undefined behavior in this case, wouldn't it? Since %s would expecting a `'\0'`

Comment: @Zaibis Yes, but the example was not a string constant. I was just giving it as another example.

Answer (score 3):

Since a define just replaces the code and you say you want to put `2` interpreted as `char` in to the `printf()` function what is not similiar to `'2'`, your just putting in that place of `%c` a escape sequence of the ASCII-code of the index 2.

if the define would be i.e.:

```
#define SQMETERS_PR_SEC '2'
```

Then it would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

you problem is, that `%c` will print a character, given it's ASCII value.

now `2` is the ASCII-value for the control-character "Start of Text", which is not printable, hence the `printf` will output a placeholder (e.g. a blank space).

if you want to print a number, use `%d` instead:

```
printf(" do foo bar at %d kul\n", 2);
```